# Parse timestamp char to int for calculation

Tags: c++, parsing, timestamp

I have a timestamp like 10:22:23 stored in a `string`. Now i want the hours and minutes in two separate variable, so i can calculate with them.

My approach was, that i store the first two digits (hours) in a `char` and the 4 and 5 digit (minute) also in a `char`. Something like

```
String timestamp = "10:22:23";
const char *timestamp_char = timestamp.c_str();
```

Now i can call each digit with `timestamp_char[]`. I want `timestamp_char[0]` and `timestamp_char[1]` in one integer, in this case "10". Also, when the time is i.e. 09:22:23, my integer should look like this "9". Same with `timestamp_char[4]` and `timestamp_char[5]`.

Comment: Do you want C or C++ solutions? Pick one or the other.

Comment: sorry for that. C++

Comment: Look at the documentation for strptime. If you're on a POSIX (ish) platform, this should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, strptime is good for this. But my solution is now with `int h, m; const char *timestamp_char = timestamp.c_str();
  sscanf(str, "%d:%d", &hr, &m);`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this could be something like:

```
std::string time = "10:22:33";
int hrs = std::stoi( time.substr( 0, 2 ) );
int mins = std::stoi( time.substr( 3,  2) );
int secs = std::stoi( time.substr( 6, 2 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int h, m; 
const char *timestamp_char = timestamp.c_str(); 
sscanf(timestamp_char, "%d:%d", &hr, &m);
```

Comment: What's `str`?  Should you be parsing `timestamp_char` instead?  If you provided some actual explanation, that might be more obvious!